# My edittext is error in the preview, but error list finds no error

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-edittext

My edittext is not shown and instead of that is showing error as the edittext.

I see where the error is, its the

```
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But i need it, how to fix?

Comment: Post your full layout..

Comment: I did but it says i dont have many details aside from the code. (Stack overflow wont let me post with full code

Comment: Are you able to run project? Preview not supporting all controls. It doesn't mean errors are there.

Comment: not all controls, only edittexts becuase of the tag

Comment: @SimplyBoost Have you added the Android Design Library to your project?

Comment: If stack overflow does not let you post full code, then you can share your code in other place (github, for example). And then post your link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was in the manifest